# Is it correct to say "talking via video"?

Tags: grammar, word-choice

Tell me please if it is correct to say *I would like to talk to you **via video*** meaning that I would like to communicate with someone face to face on the internet or skype for example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

People would know what you mean, I think. There's a huge choice of language for this particular subject, because there's not yet any consensus about a generic term to use. **Video call** is probably the most widely accepted generic term, and can be used both as a noun and a verb. Many people use non-generic terms when they mean a specific platform ("Can we **Facetime**?"), and some use them even when they are speaking generically. When using **video**, you want it as a noun or adjective. You could say "via video", "by video", and probably other ways of saying it, too.

Answer (score 2):

## video chat; video call

> Can we video chat? / Let's video chat.

or

> I'm available by video call.

Less commonly, there's also videophone:

> Please contact me by videophone.

These are all valid.